# При смене языка на linux ubuntu включается и отключается подсветка

Tags: linux, ubuntu

При смене языка на linux ubuntu включается и отключается подсветка, как это исправить? Если прописать данную команду как на фото, то происходит тоже самое, но если написать `xset led 3` то подсветка все время включена. Я хочу полностью выключить подсветку, так как она мне не нужна.

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete+ledscroll(group_lock)"    };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+ru:2+ru:3+inet(evdev)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,ru,ru
variant:    ,,
options:    grp_led:scroll
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подсветка чего?

Comment: Подсветка клавиатуры знаю название только Dialog старенькая